# Run previous build in TFS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

I have a feature in my program that has been broken in a previous build and I would like to run previous builds to determine what changeset caused the break.  Is there an easy way to do this?  I am running VS2013 pro.

Answer (score 4):

When you queue the build on the Queue build window, select the "Paramiters" tab. Then in the advanced section you'll see a "Get Version" text box. Enter the change set you want to build from in the format "C123" I.e. You want to build change set 5467 then enter `C5467` I think you can also use a label or a date time

Comment: +1 It's a good practice to simply keep an archive of old builds though, ideally using daily builds. It saves so much time when you realise something was broken and you can binary-chop through old builds to determine exactly when it broke.

Comment: Agreed, or use continuous / rolling builds and you'll know as soon as a checkin breaks the build

Comment: Yes, although even with CI, sometimes you might not notice a subtle regression in a complex app for months.

Answer (score 0):

Just log in to your TFS in the webbrowser of your choice.
There should be a complete list of all changes and of course there should be an option to get back to a specific changeset.